# How to complete a Future?

Tags: dart

I am searching for something like the following, where I return an object from a method, which can be awaited, and completed from its origin function:

```
Future<dynamic> customFunction() {
    // The following class does not exist, but I am searching for a class that would fill that gap.
    FutureWithCompletion future = FutureWithCompletion();
    () async { // A callback that represents the usecase.
      // some computation
      future.completeWith('something');
    }
    return future;
}

/// This function accesses [customFunction].
/// It should print out "something" once the computation is done.
anotherFunction() async => print(await customFunction());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html):

```
Future<String> method() {
  final completer = Completer<String>();
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => completer.complete('result'));
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: Ah, you were faster than me. I wanted to answer myself, but it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Future.value('something`);
```

otherwise use a `Completer` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html